# Weighted partitions of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, partitions

***Made an important edit to make the "partition" part of the question more clear

Let $m,n$ be positive integers. Denote $\left[ m\right] \equiv \{ 1,\ldots ,m\}$.

Let $$\mathbf{w} \equiv \left(w_1, \ldots, w_n \right) $$ be a weight, so that $ w_j \in \left[ m \right] \cup \{ 0 \} $ and $w_1 + \dots + w_n = m$.

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a matrix of dimensions $m \times n$.

For a given matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and weight $\mathbf{w}$ I want to list all possible lists, where each list consists of exactly one element from each and every row of $\mathbf{A}$, so $m$ elements in total, such that the first $ w_1 $ elements are from the first column of $\mathbf{A}$, the next $ w_2 $ elements are from the second column of $\mathbf{A}$, ... the next $ w_j $ elements are from the $j$-th column of $\mathbf{A}$, ... and the last $ w_n $ elements are from the $n$-th column of $\mathbf{A}$. (Notice that some $w_j$'s may be $ 0 $, also the $w_j$'s are not necessarily pairwise distinct)

What is a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

For the modified question, you could use [`SatisfiabilityInstances`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SatisfiabilityInstances):

```
partitionedLists[w_, A_?MatrixQ] := Module[{dim=Dimensions[A], a, x, v, f, i},
    (* array of variables *)
    a = Array[x, dim];
    
    (* variable list, transposed so that column 1 variables come before column 2, etc *)
    v = Flatten @ Transpose @ a;

    i = SatisfiabilityInstances[
        And @@ Flatten[{
            (* pick the right number for each column *)
            MapThread[
                BooleanCountingFunction[{#1}, dim[[1]]] @@ #2 &,
                {w, Transpose @ a}
            ],
            (* make sure each row has only one variable selected *)
            BooleanCountingFunction[{1}, dim[[2]]] @@@ a
        }],
        v,
        All
    ];

    f = Flatten  @ Transpose @ A;
    Pick[f, #]& /@ i
]
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[2];
w = {2, 1, 2}
A = RandomInteger[10, {5, 3}]
```

> {2, 1, 2}

> {{8, 4, 5}, {4, 7, 4}, {0, 1, 0}, {4, 3, 7}, {3, 0, 2}}

Partitioned lists:

```
partitionedLists[w, A]
```

> {{8, 4, 1, 7, 2}, {8, 4, 3, 0, 2}, {8, 4, 0, 0, 7}, {8, 0, 7, 7, 2}, {8, 0, 3,
> 4, 2}, {8, 0, 0, 4, 7}, {8, 4, 7, 0, 2}, {8, 4, 1, 4, 2}, {8, 4, 0, 4,
> 0}, {8, 3, 7, 0, 7}, {8, 3, 1, 4, 7}, {8, 3, 3, 4, 0}, {4, 0, 4, 7, 2}, {4,
> 0, 3, 5, 2}, {4, 0, 0, 5, 7}, {4, 4, 4, 0, 2}, {4, 4, 1, 5, 2}, {4, 4, 0, 5,
> 0}, {4, 3, 4, 0, 7}, {4, 3, 1, 5, 7}, {4, 3, 3, 5, 0}, {0, 4, 4, 4, 2}, {0,
> 4, 7, 5, 2}, {0, 4, 0, 5, 4}, {0, 3, 4, 4, 7}, {0, 3, 7, 5, 7}, {0, 3, 3,
> 5, 4}, {4, 3, 4, 4, 0}, {4, 3, 7, 5, 0}, {4, 3, 1, 5, 4}}

Comment: I think you read my mind regarding the handling of the ambiguity.

Comment: I have already accepted your answer, but unfortunately I made a mistake when asking my question. I should have mentioned that I wanted to list all possible aforementioned lists, but where exactly one element is taken from each and every row.

Comment: @Hellbound I don't know what the protocol is, but I don't mind you updating your question and removing the accept :)

Comment: Alright, I made the edit. Thanks